# How to Catalog Catogory Default position in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I want to arrange home at first position and about us last one and another two categories in middle

Comment: Do you have try my below solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should create category in below order

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy file from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`

Add file in below path

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml
```

You can add custom menu like below code just after or before menu code

```
<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?php echo __("Home")?></span>
    </a>
</li>

<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>

<li class="level0 level-top ui-menu-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."Yourpath"; ?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all"  role="menuitem">
        <span><?php echo __("About Ys")?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```